# How to access library jar file at run time in android?

Tags: android, fips

I have create a cryptographic module and export it as jar file.

The library need self integrity testing when loaded in order to pass the FIPS validation.

The first idea comes up to do so is to read the jar file at run time, make a hash and compare it to a signature saved somewhere.

By unzip the application apk which using the jar file, I do not find the jar. So I guess the classes in jar are saved in classes.dex, am I right? Is it possible to recover the jar from classes.dex?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an "Approved integrity technique" before you load your module. The only NIST "Approved" integrity verification methods are:
- DSA/RSA/ECDSA signature
- C/MAC or HMAC

See "6.4 Approved Integrity Techniques" in [FIPS140-2 Implementation Guidance document](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/fips140-2/FIPS1402IG.pdf).

A simple MD5/SHA-1/SHA-2 hash is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to recover the jar from classes.dex?

No.

Moreover, it would not do you a bit of good. Whoever changes your JAR would merely change the hash as well.

Comment: Is it possible to read my classes' bytecode at run time? Thanks.

Comment: @SiLuo: That I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 0):

The dex format isn't public, but there do exist a tool to extract it to a jar, its called dex2jar and can be found here http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/

Don't think it solves your problem though, just thought you wanted to know.